# Can't install Debian 9.5 on Dell Vostro 3020

Tags: debian

Downloaded the ISO of the Debian-Live 9.5.0 AMD64 - Gnome Operating System from cdimage.debian.org, made a bootable USB stick and tried installing it on a Dell Vostro 3020 Tower PC, having a 13th gen Intel i5 CPU, 16GB of RAM, running on integrated graphics and with a Micron 2450 M.2 PCIe NVMe SSD, the PC also came with a UBUNTU Operating System (22.04) already installed.

-Said PC does not support the option of a "Legacy" booting mode, just UEFI.

-The BIOS has been updated to the latest (at this time) version which was downloaded from the Dell website.

-The Secure Boot setting has been turned off, the SATA/NVMe Operation mode has been set to AHCI/NVMe.

The problem I have is that the system does not get past the "Logo Screen". It just displays the Dell logo with a small line at the top of the screen and does nothing after.
I am not prompted to install the OS or anything, it just hangs there.
It does not work with Secure Boot enabled either.

Some of the settings I tried (to no avail) to use when making the bootable USB drive:

Partition scheme: MBR, Target System: BIOS or UEFI,
Volume label: WASD,
File System: FAT32 (default) and a Cluster Size of 8192.
ISO Hybrid image settings were tried in both options.

None of these worked

I also tried with GPT (both ISO settings) still didn't work.

Any ideas please on how to install this on the PC?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for installing Debian 9.5? It’s no longer supported, the current release is 12.2.

Comment: It is probable that Debian 9.5 (EOL in June 2022) does not have any support to use a 13th Generation Intel i5 CPU (released October 2022).  You would likely need a distribution that includes at least version 6.0 of the Linux kernel to support that processor.

Comment: Thank you, it is for compatibility with other software that I require this exact version, but I'll look into seeing if that software can run on newer versions of the Debian OS as well.